# How to find current consumption of IC from datasheet?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, current, datasheet

How do we find out the current consumption of [TCAN33x family ICs](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tcan330.pdf)  from the datasheet?
I am creating a power tree diagram for my project. For that, I need to find the current consumption of each IC But In the datasheet, they have given different currents So which one do I need to choose for my power tree diagram?

And what are all the different currents?

And in some datasheets don't have current consumption so who I need to find?out

[image: Datasheet]

Comment: The consumption of a CAN transceiver is not constant, but depends on how you use this; the datasheet lists all possible cases. Only you know how you're using it.

Comment: What CL said. They have carefully listed numerous "test conditions" . Silent/Shutdown/normal... AND normal is divided into 3 categories. YOU need to determine which states your equipment will be in and for how long. For average consumption the answers should be "typically. during operation". For fault conditions eg "Dominant with bus fault) current is about three times normal-normal mode, so you'd need to know (or calculate, or guess) how many of your devices may be in each mode, worst case.

Comment: In general when making the power tree ,maximum value is used .You can take 180ma

Answer (score 0):

> *which one do I need to choose for my power tree diagram? And what are
> all the different currents?*

Page 6 of the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tcan337.pdf?ts=1711276425560&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) states what they are regarding the operational function of the device: -

[image]

If you don't understand what the operational functions of the device are you cannot make a power tree so, you need to consult with the product designer in your organization. Some (maybe all) situations will apply and possibly some won't and, in the case of quiescent (standby and shut-down) currents, they can probably be ignored.

If some data sheets don't provide currents you have to dig a little deeper and possibly talk to the suppliers of these parts.